# Test Score Program - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am supposed to be creating a program that will create an average test score using the input of the user. I also need to make sure that when the user says 'end' instead of inputting a score that the program with break and will give the user the results. However, I can not get the program to run correctly and would like some input.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#display a welcome message
print("The test Scores program")
print()
print("Enter end to stop input") #change from 999 to end
print("========================")
print()

#variables
counter = 0
score_total = 0
test_score = 0

choice = "y"

while choice.lower():
    while True:
        test_score =input("Enter test score: ")

        if test_score == "end":
            break
        elif (test_score >= 0) and (test_score <= 100):
            score_total += test_score
            counter += 1
        else:
            print("Test score must be from 0 through 100. Try again>")

    #calculate average score
    average_score = round(score_total / counter)

    #display result
    print("=======================")
    print("Total Score: ", score_total)
    print("Average Score: ", average_score)
    print()

    #see if user wants to continue
    choice = input("Continue (y/n)? ")
    print()

print("Bye")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a string and an int when you do `(test_score >= 0) and (test_score <= 100)`, you want to convert the input to an int when you are comparing it with a number.

Try this:

```
    test_score =input("Enter test score: ")

    if test_score == "end":
        break
    elif (int(test_score) >= 0) and (int(test_score) <= 100):
        score_total += int(test_score)
        counter += 1
    else:
        print("Test score must be from 0 through 100. Try again>")
```

I am simply converting test_score to an int when it is being compared to a number.

Comment: `float` can be used if test_score is non-integer.

Answer (score 0):

It's already late but this is for anyone who happened to have the same question. You can try separating 'int' from the Test_score = input("Enter test score:") :)

```
while True:
        test_score = input("Enter test score: ")
        if test_score == 'end':
            break
        test_score = int(test_score)
        if 0 <= test_score <= 100:
            score_total += test_score
            counter += 1
    
        else:
            print(
                "Test score must be from 0 through 100. Score discarded. Try again."
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test_score =input("Enter test score: ")

if test_score == "end":
    break
elif (int(test_score) >= 0) and (int(test_score) <= 100):
    score_total += int(test_score)
    counter += 1
else:
    print("Test score must be from 0 through 100. Try again>")
```